# BAT para acesso telnet passando usuário e senha

Tags: batch

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como usar um **bat** para acessar um um host via telnet  para **automatizar backup**.

Tentei chamar o **telnet**, mas. como passar o **usuário** e **senha** e serem reconhecidos.

Ele só abre o **prompt** do **telnet** e me pede login.

Estou usando esses comandos:

```
telnet 10.0.50.1
local-user=mardencmt
password=admin
ECHO %local-user%
ECHO %password%
```

Comment: Vinícius, pelo q eu sei só é possível especificar o usuário previamente, não?

Comment: Assim como segue a ajuda do TELNET: telnet [-a][-e escape char][-f log file][-l user][-t term][host [port]]

Comment: Sinceramente não sei Fabricio, rsrsrs. Primeira vez que precisei fazer isso...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

----

**O comando telnet** não oferece opções para **inserção** dos **dados** de **login**:

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vou deixar aqui duas **possíveis opções** para faze-lo via **bat/cmd com /VBS & bat/cmd com Telnet Script Tool**:

Uma opção seria **SendKey *(VBS)*** muito útil para **enviar dados** simulando uma **digitação** e enviando para os dados para o **telnet efetuar o login**

- **:: ou ::  [`Telnet Script Tool`](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)**

**Abaixo um exemplo do uso do  `SendKey (VBS)`** para enviar os dados de entrada

---

---

**1)** Exemplo em um **bat** que **gera** em **tempo de execução** um **VBS** para **efetuar** essa **tarefa**.

Apenas **substituir** nas linhas abaixo os **respectivos valores** para as **variáveis**:

***[*usuario*]  [*senha*] [*cmd*]***

*set  "*usuario*=**mardencmt**" & set  "*senha*=**admin**"*

*set  "*cmd*=**telnet 10.0.50.1**"*

---

### [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls

echo/ & mode con cols=77 lines=30& color 9F

set "_usuario_=cisco_user" & set "_senha_=4LoCk007XSwT001"
set "_cmd_=telnet.exe 192.168.0.254"

>"%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs"^
    (
     echo/ Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject^("WScript.Shell"^)
     echo/ StrPwd  = "!_senha_!"
     echo/ StrUser = "!_usuario_!"
     echo/ for i=1 To Len^(StrUser^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrUser,i,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 250
     echo/ Next
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 500
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ for j=1 To Len^(StrPwd^)
     echo/     x = Mid^(StrPwd,j,1^)
     echo/     WshShell.SendKeys x
     echo/     Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ Next 
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "dir"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "exit"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     echo/ Wscript.Sleep 200
     echo/ WshShell.SendKeys "({ENTER})"
     ) 

set "_temp_vbs=%temp%\_temp_file_4vbs_.vbs" &  start "" /b !_cmd_!
@"%Windir%\System32\cScript.exe" //nologo "!_temp_vbs!" <nul & del /q /f "!_temp_vbs!" & goto :eof
```

---

**2)** Que tal usar o **[`Telnet Script Tool`](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)** para automatizar o envio dos dados de entrada?

- **[`Telnet Script Tool`](https://www.freewareweb.com/cgi-bin/archive.cgi?ID=645)**   - Veja **Pergunta/Resposta** **tratando** esse **tema** no **[`SO/EN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201716/telnet-session-with-batch-file/29234144#29234144)**

---

- Abaixo segue um **exemplo** do uso dessa **ferramenta** que faz a **inserção**  usando o **conteúdo** de um **arquivo texto**:  **`"%temp%\script_ts.scr"`**

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & cls & mode con cols=77 lines=30

echo/ & color 9F & set "_usuario_=mardencmt" & set "_senha_=admin" & set "_ip_porta_=10.0.50.1 23"

>"%temp%\script_ts.scr" ^
    (
     echo/!_ip_porta_! & echo/WAIT "User Name" & echo/SEND "!_usuario_!\m" & echo/WAIT "Passoword" & echo/SEND "!_senha_!\m"
    ) && "%temp%\TST10.exe" /r:"%temp%\script_ts.scr" /o:"%temp%\output_ts.txt" & goto :eof
```